# How do I change ColdFusion Help to show ColdFusion 8 Documentation, instead of ColdFusion 9 Documentation?

Tags: ide, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I love ColdFusion Builder. But I don't like that the help only has CF9 Documentation. Is there any way to change this to have ColdFusion 8 Documenation?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/index.html

Or I don't understand the question.

Comment: I suppose I did misunderstand the question, though. I guess you refer to context help…

Comment: Ha. Yes, I know where to find CF Help online. But I'd like to access CF 8 Help in CF Builder.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about "Code Assist", you can find that under

`Windows | Preferences | ColdFusion | Profiles | Editor | Code Assist`

Change the "Code Assist Dictionary Version" to the version you want. Versions 7 through 10 are available.

(This is ColdFusion Builder 2 Update 1)

If you're content with online help, I find [CF Quick Docs](http://cfquickdocs.com) more useful than the official Adobe Livedocs.